# org export: "no output was produced to write to file"

Tags: org-export

Sample file:

```
* hello
* goodbye
* some source
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session :file py224158lK.png :exports code
  print ("this will not work")
#+END_SRC
```

The text in this file will yield error `No output was produced to write to a file' when I attempt to export it to any format (org-export-as-html, org-export-to-markdown, etc).

This is incredibly frustrating, because, not only can I not figure out what I've done to cause this failure (this used to work), but this is the worst possible moment for this error. Why might this be failing here?

Relevant: If the `*some source` header is removed, the code does export to file successfully,. In fact, the file seemingly successfully exports so long as the `:file` specification is not included.